# Open source crime incident reporting tool with mapping web app

Tags: open-source, web-apps, maps, reporting, gis

I'm looking for an incident reporting tool that meets these requirements,

- Provides a web interface
- Can be run on Linux
- Open Source
- Has a map where one can report crimes linked to specific places
- Can add notes to each crime reported

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- Has an iPhone and/or android app
- The app can support geotagging for finding a location and plotting a crime at that location

Comment: It's not going to be used to report crime, but that's the closest use case I could think of...